# Filter google maps markers on option selected

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, maps

I'm trying to filter my markers by categories based on a select so whenever a user choose one category the map should only show those markers with the same category, I did something and it worked half of the time because some of the markers were not refreshing on option selected:

```
const [filtereds, setFiltereds] = useState([])

const searchCategories = (selected) => {
    setFiltereds([])
    if(isSelected){
        bidders.map(item => item.categories.filter(categories => 
            {
                return categories.Category === selected ? setFiltereds((prevState) => [...prevState, item]) : console.log("")
            }))
        }
    console.log(filtereds)
}
```

I would like to do this in a different way if it's possible, what I did here is filter them before passing them to the maps component.

Here is where I handle the selected option:

```
const selectedOption = (opt) => {
    console.log("Option: ",opt);
    //maybe can I filter them here?
}
```

Comment: Post the rest of your code including your `setFiltereds` function and anything that's using `bidders` if you want a solution. Otherwise I can just give you a general tip. Store all your markers as properties of an object that contains any additional information your app is using, like categories. Then in your category change event you can turn the markers that match on and those that don't off ie: `.setMap(null)` for off, `.setMap(map)` for on.

Comment: that's what I did, first i used the above function to filter all the markers based on the option selected and then add all those markers to the `filtered` array so then I onlye needed to pass the array as a prop to the map component. I added more code (code i'm working on right now)

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with that approach. It's been a while and the API has probably evolved, but another approach was using something like layers. I only had to use it once a long time ago but it wasn't for this purpose. It was because there were so many markers on the map that we had to have a system for limiting the amount displayed based on the users zoom level. Assuming you don't need that, I don't see the problem with your current approach.